# Is there a way to install nginx using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, terraform

I want to include the below script in my terraform file and execute it to install nginix on my aws instance.

I would like to use yaml and I am not familiar with it. Any idea in how to make this a yaml file?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: This may help you https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/deployment.html

Answer (score 2):

that looks like a Kubernetes configuration for a deployment so your server would need to be part of a Kubernetes cluster to run that.

If you’re running Kubernetes you could run this through [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/deployment.html)  although people generally run [kubectl to create a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/deploy-app/deploy-intro/).

If you’re looking to just install nginx as a service using Terraform you could use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html).

Personally from my perspective for installing services I’d look at [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html)

Comment: I was able to write an ansible playbook that installs nginx on my server. Now i would love to use this playbook in terraform but i am having issues converting to a terraform file. i will greatly appreciate help around that. The playbook is as below
---

- hosts: AppServer

  become: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Installs nginx web server

    apt:

      name: nginx

      state: present

      update_cache: true

    notify:

    - start nginx

  handlers:

  - name: start nginx

    service:

      name: nginx

      state: present

Comment: Hi no playbook in comment, can you add to the question

Answer (score 2):

First this won't work on a vanilla EC2 instance. This is a kubernetes manifest so you must run it against k8s cluster using `kubectl`.

Assuming you have a k8s cluster, then to use this yaml in terraform you can create a `null_resource` with `local-exec` or `remote-exec` provisioner which must have `kubectl` configured to access your k8s cluster where nginx will be installed. Then simply run `kubectl apply -f <path-to-nginx.yaml>` inside the terraform provisioner.

Answer (score 1):

You could resort to the [Terraform Helm provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/helm/index.html) to install nginx on EKS (Amazon's Kubernetes Engine (Elastic Kubernetes Service)).

[nginx helm documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently tried to do the same and stumbled across provisioners.

```
connection {
host     = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.terra-vm.public_ip_address
type     = "ssh"
user     = "username"    # Replace with the username for your VM
password = "Password1" # Replace with the password for your VM
```

}

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
 inline = [
  "sudo apt-get update",
  "sudo apt-get install -y nginx",
  "sudo service nginx start",
]
```

}

This is on azure but worked for me

Bare in mind i am a beginner so if there is a better way, it can be researched